# how to fetch one word at time in script & add in diffent command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sh

file:- jobstream
ram
ramesh
nikhil
nehal
jon
abc
abd
afg
rtyu
ert
eee
& so on because in this file there are more 500 words

I Want to fetch one word at a time & put in different command  in different file

file:extract

composer di @#ram > file

this command will extract detail info of ram from database. & want to upend this in other file  keeping 2 line black in between. but 1st i want to fetch one word at a time in above command
composer di @#variable

Comment: You can iterate each line in file :- `while read line; do echo $line;done < jobstream`

Comment: but where should i mention file name from which we want to read file.. can you give proper command.. consider file name:-nikhil from which we have read line at a time

Comment: `while read line; do echo $line; done < nikhil`. Redirecting nikhil file to while loop.

Comment: got it.. bit if want to get output of below command in other file the what should i do help?                                                                                     while read line; do composer di @#$line;done < hr_jobstream

Answer (score 0):

You can take input from file and redirect to another file using following bash script:

```
while read line;
do
    "print something"
done < hr_jobstream > another_file
```

Above while loop will read from `hr_jobstream` and into `another_file`.

Comment: `echo "" >data
while read line
 do
name=composer di @#$line
echo $name>>data
done < hr_jobstream`